# Why is Google Chrome not sending If-None-Match headers in HTTP requests?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-cache

I'm hitting this url:

http://www.spotlight.com/photo/~30x50/ffffff/crop/1/M195605.jpg

in Google Chrome  40.0.2214.115 m and in Firefox 33.0.2

In Firefox, when I press F5 to refresh the page, it sends these request headers:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-GB,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Host    www.spotlight.com
If-None-Match   w/PTxYoQtZLHNE2hqq5W0w==
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
```

In Chrome, I get these headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:www.spotlight.com
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
```

The response includes an HTTP ETag header. On subsequent requests to the same URL, Firefox sends the correct If-None-Match ETag header, but Chrome is sending Pragma:no-cache and not sending a If-None-Match header.

Any idea why Chrome is doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check that you don't have checked "Disable cache" is chrome dev tools [image]